# Is it possible to update settings for a Google service account?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-calendar-api, service-accounts

Is it possible to update the settings for a service account?

I want to change the [defaultEventLength](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings) for calendars managed by a service account I am using with a bot.

As far as I can tell, there is no `update` method through the Calendar API for settings such as these.

It seems from the wording in the documentation that settings should be updated through the UI, but as far as I'm aware that is not possible for a service account.

> Setting resources represent settings that users can change from the Calendar UI, such as the user's time zone. They can be retrieved via list and get methods. - [Calendar API Reference](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/settings)

Is there really no way to change the settings from the defaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is still unavailable, and I just created this [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179826090) for you to follow.